# How to classify timestamp?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

Here is my table:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |    timestamp    |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | 1452001861      |    -- yesterday
| 2  | 1452088272      |    -- today
| 3  | 1452088283      |    -- today
| 4  | 1451915461      |    -- last week
| 5  | 1452001861      |    -- yesterday
| 6  | 1452088263      |    -- today
| 7  | 1252388263      |    -- out of {today, yesterday, last week}
| 8  | 1452088312      |    -- today
| 9  | 1452001762      |    -- yesterday
| 10 | 1222388263      |    -- out of {today, yesterday, last week}
| 12 | 1451915459      |    -- last week
+----+-----------------+
```

Now I want to select like this:

```
+----+-----------------+---------------+
| id |    timestamp    |     range     |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
| 1  | 1452001861      |  yesterday    |
| 2  | 1452088272      |  today        |
| 3  | 1452088283      |  today        |
| 4  | 1451915461      |  last week    |
| 5  | 1452001861      |  yesterday    |
| 6  | 1452088263      |  today        |
| 7  | 1252388263      |  out          |
| 8  | 1452088312      |  today        |
| 9  | 1452001762      |  yesterday    |
| 10 | 1222388263      |  out          |
| 12 | 1451915459      |  last week    |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
//                             ^ this column isn't a real column
```

Well, All what I can do is selecting just today:

```
SELECT
  id,
  date_time
FROM
  viewed
WHERE
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_time`), '%Y-%m-%d') >= (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

As I said, This query ^ selects just today timestamps.

---

**My Question:** Now I want to know, how can I expand my query to {today, yesterday - last week} ?

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in classification for "Today", "Yesterday", "Last week" in MySQL. All you could do is calculate the days since today (something like `DATEDiFF(CURDATE(), timestamp) AS daysSinceToday`) and then have your PHP script classify it (`if($daysSinceToday == 0) //today// elseif ($daysSinceToday == 1) //yesterday// elseif ($daysSinceToday > 7) //Last 7 days//`). When you want to print them out like on SO, then you'd also have to have them ordered by MySQL first.

Answer (score 2):

An incomplete answer to get you started...

```
SELECT CASE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(1452001861)) 
       WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 'yesterday'
       WHEN CURDATE() THEN 'today' END x;
```

Comment: The `DATE` conversion figures, I think, as a nice improvement of the problem statement, in that it prevents some tricky manual date and time calculations reinvented.